# Copying an existing XML file to a new XML file

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I have an existing XML file that has the following start element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mynms SYSTEM 'mynms20.dtd'>
<mynms version="2.0" xmlns="mynms20.xsd"> <!-- This is the troublesome line-->
<cmData type="actual">
   <header>
      <log dateTime="2011-10-17T06:07:07" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">InternalValues are used</log>
   </header>
 .....
 </cmData>
```

I'm reading this file using c#'s **XMLReader** and then altering certain elements of the file as above and outputing the new xml in another file using c#'s **XMLWriter**.

So when the XMLReader reads in an element, I have the following:

```
writer.WriteStartElement(xmlReader.Prefix, xmlReader.Name, null);
writer.WriteAttributes(xmlReader, true);   <!-- This causes the assertion. Take this out then everything is OK -->
```

But I get an exception stating **The prefix ' ' cannot be redefined from ' ' to 'mynms20.xsd' within the same start element tag.** <--- What does this mean and how can I just copy the namespace and attributes over to another file?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding namespace? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfche0ka.aspx

Comment: Just curious, did you consider using XSLT?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742.aspx

Comment: If you know the format of the XML file, and your not going to have to add new tags in, you can create a class to hold it and the stored values from the file. Then you have your XML as an object that you can modify.

You can then create another instance of this class, change whatever properties/fields you want (setting the XMLs attributes or what not), and save it to a different name.